# How to make SHA1 in c that returns raw output?

Tags: c, sha1

Please refer to http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php

If the optional raw_output is set to TRUE, then the sha1 digest is instead returned in raw binary format with a length of 20, otherwise the returned value is a 40-character hexadecimal number.

My current code is

```
char *concat = "somestring";
int i = 0;
unsigned char hash[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];
char buf[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH*2];

memset(buf, 0x0, SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH*2);
memset(hash, 0x0, SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH);

SHA1((unsigned char *)concat, strlen(concat), hash);

for (i=0; i < SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) {
    sprintf((char*)&(buf[i*2]), "%02x", hash[i]);
}

printf("<<sha1=%s>>\n", buf);
```

It works fine but return string in hex.

What is the best approach to achieve that?

Thanks.

Comment: Please show/describe the desired output/result. An array of 20 bytes with the value? Printing that won't be possible (at least won't have a reasonable chance of being printable characters).

Comment: I’m wondering what the PHP documentation has to do with this. In any case, read your code. You have a part that converts the hash into hex. Don’t use that code.

Comment: @Yunnosch I don't know how it should look like.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen The link is just an example of the desired behavior in PHP. Yes, that part you are referring to is definitely incorrect, it was written before I realized that the result should be presented in different way. Can toy advise how to read the digest value in my case?

Answer (score 2):

The solution was very simple an obvious. I just had to change the format:

from

```
sprintf((char*)&(buf[i*2]), "%02x", hash[i]);
```

to

```
sprintf((char*)&(buf[i*2]), "%c", hash[i]);
```

Thank you all to pointing me on the correct spot!

Answer (score 0):

What you have already receives the hash in raw form (assuming SHA1 works), if you want to write that just do so (using fwrite or the like), but it won't be human-readable like the hex form is.

Comment: I don't need it to be human readable, it'll be used in another operation (base64).